# Is it possible to create download link for Left Joined classic report?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have classic report in the page, which has the following SQL query:

```
SELECT CELLS.ID, CELLS.NAME, CELLS.NUM, CELLS.AC_ID, AC.SERIAL,AC.FILE_NAME, AC.FILE_DATA
FROM CELLS 
LEFT JOIN AC
ON CELLS.AC_ID = AC.ID
WHERE CELLS.AC_ID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CELLS.NUM
```

I would like to have download link for `AC.FILE_DATA`, which is BLOB. So in Attributes `FILE_DATA` column I set the following:

```
Type: Download BLOB
Table Name: AC
BLOB Column: FILE_DATA
Primary Key Column 1: ID
```

The page then is generating error in the place of classic report region:

> Error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number
>   conversion error

Looking in Debug log shows some more:

> Exception in "AC Region": Sqlerrm: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value
>   error: character to number conversion error Backtrace: ORA-06512: at
>   "APEX_050100.WWV_RENDER_REPORT3", line 7965

Without `AC.FILE_DATA` in left join there is no exception. So can I actually have blob download column when using joins in report query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it has nothing to do with (left) join but the way you create the *download* link. It should **NOT** be the BLOB column name, but this:

```
dbms_lob.getlength(ac.file_data) download
```

Or, applied to your query,

```
SELECT CELLS.ID, 
       CELLS.NAME, 
       CELLS.NUM, 
       CELLS.AC_ID, 
       AC.SERIAL,
       AC.FILE_NAME, 
       --
       dbms_lob.getlength(AC.FILE_DATA) download  --> this
FROM CELLS 
LEFT JOIN AC
ON CELLS.AC_ID = AC.ID
WHERE CELLS.AC_ID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CELLS.NUM
```

"Download"  column settings:

- Type: Download BLOB
- Table name: AC
- BLOB Column: FILE_DATA
- Primary Key Column 1: ID

Save, Run - should be just fine.

Comment: This brings download link indeed, but an attempt to download it, gives `500 Internal Server Error`, although data, mime type and file name are there.

Comment: While answering to your question, I created an example (so that I wouldn't write *stupidities*) and downloaded the image without any problem. Mime type & File name aren't necessary; they just tell you how to "Open" the file (JPGs are opened with an image viewer, PDFs with some PDF viewer, such as Adobe Acrobat Reader, etc.), while File name is used to help you "Save" the file (otherwise, its name is just "download" with no extension). Shortly: no idea what might be going on. If possible, create an example on apex.oracle.com and provide credentials so that we could see it.

Comment: I'll try to replicate it on apex.oracle.com, but one thing is clear, when I eliminate join and use directly `SELECT ID, SERIAL, FILE_NAME, dbms_lob.getlength(FILE_DATA) AS FILE_DATA
FROM AC` then download works just fine. Perhaps something to do with ID, when it should find the blob...

Comment: In Download URL there is parameter called `k1`. I took the value of `k1` when I had no-join query and it was pointing to right ID in `AC` table. Then I looked into `k1` value when using left join query and it was pointing to ID in CELLS table. If in column settings I've specified `AC` table with its ID, how it's going to find proper data? It could be that apex is using ID from left join query in order to lookup data from AC table, which is plain wrong. But I have no way to specify left join query in data column settings...

Comment: Basically my assumption was right. What I did is I modified left join slightly: `SELECT CELLS.ID as CELLID, CELLS.AC_ID as ID`... which solved `500 Internal Server Error` and I was able to download.

Comment: Hooray! I'm glad you made it work! (I went offline, it is quite late here; sory for not responding earlier)